# How do I put a text file into a SQL Server 2012 field

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table call it `tbl1` with a field `ASCII_file nvarchar(MAX)`.

I want to put file `'c:xyz.ght'` into field `ASCII_file` using SSMS SQL Insert statement.

Also for existing records is using update the only way to get the files into the field.  I tried copy the file but paste did not show up when I tried to paste the file into the field.  Is there any easier way than using a SQL update?

Comment: Insert or update? Look up `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do something like this, with a simple insert statement?

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 
VALUES ('c:xyz.ght');
```

And an update statement:

```
UPDATE tbl1 
SET ASCII_file ='c:xyz.ght'
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

If you want to read a content of a file:

```
BULK INSERT tbl1  
FROM 'c:\temp\file.txt'
WITH 
  (
     ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
  )
```

Comment: because they specifically mentioned also wanting the ability to update existing records

Comment: Not in the same action, it seems like the OP asked how to `insert` AND how to `update`.

Comment: Would that just not add the name of the table instead of the contents of the file?  What if in one field I wanted the name of the file 'c:\xyz.ght and in another field I wanted the contents of the file hoe would SQL server know what I wanted ?

Comment: @John, SQL won't know.. I'm not sure what exactly you need, can you write it in details?

Comment: I want to put the contents (The text of the book that is contained within the dos file ) into a SQL Table

Comment: You can use `OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:xyz.txt', SINGLE_NCLOB)` to read the file. (see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1643/using-openrowset-to-read-large-files-into-sql-server/ for examples or look up `OPENROWSET` in Books Online)

Comment: I have a table with many fields and I know how to get data into those fields if I type('bla bla bla', 1, etc.  but how do I get the contents of the book into another field

Comment: Can you show me the entire SQL command that would execute properly

Comment: Do you want to update an existing row in your table, or you want to add a new row to you table with the content of your book?

Comment: the term rowterminator seems to imply that the single file contains multiple records but that is not the case.  I have record#1 = file anem1 (contents of the file in a field) the I might want to inert another single SQL record with a diferent book name and it's associated text.

Comment: Bulk insert is not what I want to do. Bulk Insert Imports a data file into a database table.  I want the file in a specific single field in a single record so if the table was empty before after this operation it will now contain a single record and one field will contain the book text and other fields will contain various other data about the book

Comment: You said "If you want to read a content of a file:"  but I DO NOT WANT TO READ ANY FILE JUST PUT THE CONTENTS INTO A SINGLE FIELD IN A SINGLE RECORD.